# How to do a screen capture without getting an OOM (out of memory) exception?

Tags: java, android

I want to screencapture and save a view.

I think I can create a bitmap as big as the view and draw the view on this bitmap. In this situation, the view's width is the same as the screen's width, and its height may be more than the screen.

So it is easy to get an OOM problem. Is there any way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need transparency, you can use `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` instead of `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` :

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

This reduces memory usage by half.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'll try it !